# React js Render works before Fetch get value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I have one component App.js which has a fetch api with credential . In render i have condition if last view is 1 open image view component else go to gallery component

Like This 
[Condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5OrI.png)
Now this issue is that when app.js load api load in second time and first render work then again fetch api get data and ImageView this.state.data is null and so in imageView component i can't get props.

Api call service file

```
import fetchival from 'fetchival';

    const CLIENT_ID = 'your id';
    const apiBase = 'https://api.imgur.com/3';
    const request = fetchival(apiBase, {
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Client-ID ' + CLIENT_ID
      }
    });

    export function searchGallery(section = 'hot',) {

        return request('gallery/' + section ).get();

    }
```

App.js main file

```
 async loadImages(section,sort,page = 0) {

        try {
          let result = await searchGallery(section, sort, page);
          this.setState({data: result.data, page: page, loaded: true});
        } catch (e) {

        }

      }
      onClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault() 
        this.loadImages(e.target.text.toLowerCase());
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        this.loadImages();
      }

      render() {

        return (
            <div className="warpper">
              this.state.imageView ? 
                        <ImageView {...this.state.data[this.state.activeID]}
                            _closeImageView={this._closeImageView.bind(this)} />
                            :
                        <Gallery data={this.state.data}
                            _openImageView={this._openImageView.bind(this)} />
            </div>

        )


Image View Component is not geting this.props from app js
    class ImageView extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div className="imageview-wrapper fadeIn">
                    <div className="imageview">
                        <Image CSSClass="imageview-image"
                            src={this.props.src}
                            alt={this.props.name} />
                        <div className="imageview-info">
                            <button className="imageview-close" onClick={this.props._closeImageView}>x</button>
                            <h2>{this.props.name}</h2>
                            <p>{this.props.desc}</p>
                            <h3>Tags</h3>
                            <ul>
                                {this.props.tags.map(tag => <li>{tag}</li>)}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. Async requests are just that, async--you need to handle rendering before the async request completes.

Comment: I agree with @Dave Newton, please clarify what your issue is, I'm not quite sure what your question is.

Comment: @DaveNewton  issue is that first data should come from api the render should work but in my case first i get state as null then render start then when i get data in state 2nd time then again render works which make  <ImageView {...this.state.data} null with no data in it when i click

Comment: I'm the request is async--you have to be able to handle rendering before the data is available, or re-architect.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a constructor in the `Imageview` class, to get the props from the `App.js`.

Example:

```
class ImageView extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.setState(initialState you want to use)
    }
    render() { ...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No you don't; if no constructor is provided the default constructor is used. Props are available without an explicit constructor.

Comment: You only need an explicit constructor if you want to use `props` in the ctor, like to set the initial state based on those props etc.

Comment: I have Image view component but it is receiving empty props as i said first time fetch return null data so this.state.data is null passed and in second time fetch return data .. so imagview component has no props